# How to disable terminal/node's truncating of a large object after console.logging it

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console.log

I did some computation and stored it into an object in a .js file with the .js file console.logging the object in the last line. I run this file in node on the terminal but it has so many kev/value pairs that the terminal truncates the lines and only shows me the last 200 lines or so. Is there a way to see the entirely of this object through the terminal?

Comment: So the issue _isn't with node or javascript itself_ but with the _terminal window buffer_? If so it would depend on your system. Eg on windows you can do `node scipt.js | more`, or pipe to a file and read it back etc. Or do you need to have the terminal show it all without any user input or indirection?

Comment: Use `less` or `more` depending on what's available on your OS.

Comment: Alternatively, configure your terminal to use an infinite scrollback buffer. Note: the terminal is not bash, it is the program that draws the window that bash runs in. In rare circumstances (like booting in text mode without a GUI) the terminal is a piece of hardware (your graphics card). In the old days the terminal was a piece of hardware that looks like a monitor + keyboard.

Comment: how about `fs.writeFileSync('some.json', JSON.stringify(someObj));` ?